# Pymel: How do I extract these vector floats from a complex .TXT file?

Tags: python, vector, pymel

I am having trouble wrapping my head around how I would extract the float values from a complex text file in Pymel. I am not a programmer, I am an artist, however I am in need of creating a script for a specific workflow process and I have a beginner level knowledge of python.

My goal: to create objects in 3D space with (x,y,z) coordinates parsed from a specific text file from another program.

Ex. of text file:

> point 1                                                           8.740349    -4.640922   103.950059
>   point 2                                                         8.520906    3.447561    116.580496
>   point 3                                                         4.235010    -7.562914   99.632423
>   etc., etc

there's much more space in my text file between the point #'s and the vector floats.

I want to create a dictionary that I will use to create my objects in my 3D program.

For example,

> myDictionary = {(point 1),[8.740349,-4.640922,103.950059]), etc. }.

This is my code snippet so far:

```
def createLocators():
global filePath 
global markerNum
global markerCoord  
print "getting farther! :)"
with open(filePath,'r') as readfile:
    for line in readfile:           
        if "point" in line:             
            Types = line.split('                                                            ')
            markerNum = [Type[1] for Type in Types]
            markerCoord = [Type[2] for Type in Types]
            print markerNum, markerCoord
```

As you can see in the code, the space between the information is long. I figure if I can remove that space I can get two data sets that will be easier to work with. There is also many more lines in the text document that I don't care about, hence the if statement to filter only lines that start with "point". When I run createLocator() to test to see if it's splitting up the lines into my two lists it runs fine, but the print looks empty to me.

ex.

> [' '] [' ']

I've tried googling and searching answers here on SO, and searching both Pymel and regular python documentation for what I'm doing wrong or better approaches, but I have to admit the extent of my knowledge ends here.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better and more efficient way to extract the data I need that I'm missing?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you probably do not want to be splitting on that massive string of spaces. In fact what you almost certainly want is to just use `line.split()` with no arguments, as this will split apart all text on any kind, and any amount, of whitespace. i.e:

```
>>> 'A B      C\t\n\t   D'.split()
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Then, assuming the format you've shown is correct, you should need need to get `Types[2:5]`, i.e. the second, third, and fourth elements of `Types`, for the coordinates.

Beyond this, you should not be using capital names for local variables, and you should not be using global variables. Use function arguments instead, and rename `Types` to `split_line` or something.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked perfectly. I fixed my code and it works like a dream.